# Split a string by space or by \n

Tags: java

I would like to split a string by two delimeters: a space (" ") or a new line (\n).

What I've tried:

```
message.split("\\r?\\n? ");
```

It does split by space, but not by \n, turning:

> The way I see it we got two options. Option one, we take the easy way
>   out. It's quick and painless. I'm not a fan of option one. Option two,
>   We fight.

into:

```
[The, way, I, see, it, we, got, two, options., Option, one,, we, take, the, easy, way, out., It's, quick, and, painless., I'm, not, a, fan, of, option, one.Option, two,, We, fight.]
```

Note that `one.Option` is one cell in the array.

Comment: Is your newline followed by a space?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Well there's the problem. You need to use a `|` if you want to match either or.

Comment: If you don't mind the delimiter being a little more generic, you could split on any number of whitespace characters ~ `.split("\\s+")`

Comment: using .split("\\s+") still gives the same result

Comment: It's not clear from your question what your desired result is and what it is you're actually getting. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It was my fault, it is 100% working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, try `"\\s+"` to split on one or more whitespace characters. This includes space, tab, newline, carriage-return, line-feed, etc so it might be a bit too large a hammer for what you want.

```
final String message = "The way I see it we got two options. Option one, we take the easy way\n" +
        "out. It's quick and painless. I'm not a fan of option one. Option two,\n" +
        "We fight.";
System.out.println(String.join(", ", message.split("\\s+")));
```

Produces

> The, way, I, see, it, we, got, two, options., Option, one,, we, take, the, easy, way, out., It's, quick, and, painless., I'm, not, a, fan, of, option, one., Option, two,, We, fight.

Comment: thanks, both suggestions did the job (I've missused Phill's method at the first place).

Answer (score 2):

```
"\\r?\\n? "
```

This tells it to split by either `"\\r\\n "` or `"\\n "` or `"\\r "` or `" "`, but never by `"\\r"` or `"\\n"` or `"\\r\\n"` without the space.

The following will tell it to split by any consecutive combination of `"\\r"`, `"\\n"` and `" "` with at least one character:

```
"[\\r\\n ]+"
```